# English to Hindi translation LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying to implement English to Hindi translation using Deep Learning LSTM. But when I train the model it shows 'nan' loss in both actual and validation.

Link of text file containing translation pairs-: http://www.manythings.org/anki/

Below is my Jupyter notebook code-:

```
import string
import re
from numpy import array, argmax, random, take, delete
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Embedding, Bidirectional, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import optimizers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function to read raw text file
def read_text(filename):
    # open the file
    file = open(filename, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8')
    # read all text
    text = file.read()
    file.close()
    return text

# split a text into sentences
def to_lines(text):
    sents = text.strip().split('\n')
    sents = [i.split('\t') for i in sents]
    return sents

data = read_text("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Language Translator New/hin.txt")
eng_hin = to_lines(data)
eng_hin = array(eng_hin)

eng_hin = delete(eng_hin, 2, axis=1)

# Remove punctuation
eng_hin[:,0] = [s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for s in eng_hin[:,0]]
eng_hin[:,1] = [s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for s in eng_hin[:,1]]

# convert to lowercase
for i in range(len(eng_hin)):
    eng_hin[i,0] = eng_hin[i,0].lower()
    eng_hin[i,1] = eng_hin[i,1].lower()

# empty lists
eng_l = []
hin_l = []

# populate the lists with sentence lengths
for i in eng_hin[:,0]:
    eng_l.append(len(i.split()))

for i in eng_hin[:,1]:
    hin_l.append(len(i.split()))

print(max(eng_l))
print(max(hin_l))

# function to build a tokenizer
def tokenization(lines):
    tokenizer = Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(lines)
    return tokenizer

# prepare english tokenizer
eng_tokenizer = tokenization(eng_hin[:, 0])
eng_vocab_size = len(eng_tokenizer.word_index) + 1

eng_length = 25
print('English Vocabulary Size: %d' % eng_vocab_size)

# prepare Hindi tokenizer
hin_tokenizer = tokenization(eng_hin[:, 1])
hin_vocab_size = len(hin_tokenizer.word_index) + 1

hin_length = 25
print('Hindi Vocabulary Size: %d' % hin_vocab_size)

# encode and pad sequences
def encode_sequences(tokenizer, length, lines):
    # integer encode sequences
    seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(lines)
    # pad sequences with 0 values
    seq = pad_sequences(seq, maxlen=length, padding='post')
    return seq

# Model Building
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, test = train_test_split(eng_hin, test_size=0.2, random_state = 12)

# prepare training data
trainX = encode_sequences(eng_tokenizer, eng_length, train[:, 0])
trainY = encode_sequences(hin_tokenizer, hin_length, train[:, 1])

# prepare validation data
testX = encode_sequences(eng_tokenizer, eng_length, test[:, 0])
testY = encode_sequences(hin_tokenizer, hin_length, test[:, 1])

# build NMT model
def build_model(in_vocab, out_vocab, in_timesteps, out_timesteps, units):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(in_vocab, units, input_length=in_timesteps, mask_zero=True))
    model.add(LSTM(units))
    model.add(RepeatVector(out_timesteps))
    model.add(LSTM(units, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(out_vocab, activation='softmax'))
    return model

model = build_model(hin_vocab_size, eng_vocab_size, hin_length, eng_length, 512)
rms = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=rms, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

filename = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Language Translator New/Englis_Hindi_Checkpoints/model.h1.31_dec_19'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filename, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')

history = model.fit(trainX, trainY.reshape(trainY.shape[0], trainY.shape[1], 1), 
          epochs=100, batch_size=64, 
          validation_split = 0.2,
          callbacks=[checkpoint], verbose=1)
model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Language Translator New/Englis_Hindi_Checkpoints/eng2hin.h5')
```

When I try to fit the model, it runs but shows 'nan' in loss. Please help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: Did you double-check that your data is properly encoded. That is given word ids in the encoded sequences, you can recover the original?

Comment: I ran your code with vocab_sizes swapped at the line calling function build_model. This time loss values were showing fine. From this, I doubts that your code was written for eng-hin instead of hin-eng. There is also shape mismatch between the trainY and shape of last dense layer. Correcting these things may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @sreagm. I've  solved by swapping vocab_sizes, as earlier I was doing Hindi to English but I want English to Hindi. Now another problem rises of validation loss keeps on increasing but training loss gets decreased. What can I do to reduce validation loss?

Comment: Are you sure, the data is fed as eng-hin not the other way around. Also, when I checked the shape of last dense layer was (None, x, y) but your trainY had shape (x,y,1) . Swapping the vocab_sizes worked because it was written for hin-eng. I think swapping the data might be the right solution. Also double checking the number of samples in the dataset and building the model accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, it usually happens because the loss function / optimizer isn't suiting the network calculations. I recently used this network to create a calculator. Try using `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` and `optimizer='adam'` and see if it works.